# Using "access callback" and "access arguments" provided with hook_permission

Tags: routes

how can I check user's access first based on some permission and if user passed this check then execute `access callback` function with some parameters in path, some thing like this:

```
$items['order/add/%node'] = array(
  'title' => 'Place new order',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('order_add_form', 2),
  'access callback' => 'order_add_access',
  'access arguments' => array('place order', 2),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'order'),
  'file' => 'order.page.inc',
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean there but your code already has a custom access callback specified as well as access arguments?

You could have an access callback like this:

```
/**
 * Add order access callback
 */
function order_add_access($op, $node){

 switch ($op) {
   case 'place order':
   // Return true, if logged in user has administer nodes permission
   // and node status is published.
   if (user_access('administer nodes') && $node->status == 1) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   break;
 }
 return FALSE; // default

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the first item of the access arguments is the string for the permission the user should have to access the menu item, you could use the following code.

```
function order_add_access($permission, $node) {
  if (user_access($permission)) {
    // Check any node property, and return TRUE when the user should access the menu item.
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```